# Crashing after upgrade to MySQL 8.0.31

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

We recently upgraded to MySQL 8.0.31 on RDS. The upgrade went fine, but a couple days later the instance crashed because of data corruption and wouldn't restart. We ended up having to go boot in innodb_force_recovery, take a logical dump, and restore back to an older version.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? This was not the same data corruption problem from 8.0.29 as we have not run any DDL since the upgrade, so it must be something new and unique to 8.0.31.

Here are some examples of the errors that started happening:

```
[MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: btr0cur.cc:3660:rec thread 22349876958976

[MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: row0ins.cc:267:!cursor->index->is_committed() thread 22766529312512

[MY-012855] [InnoDB] Clustered record for sec rec not found index
```

Seems like the last couple versions of MySQL have had gamebreaking data corruption bugs -- 8.0.29 was particularly bad. Is there a currently known good version that's also supported? Our current version is about to go out of support.